# deploy an APK in chrome OS. It is posible?

Tags: android, apk, google-chrome-os

I have an apk (android app) and I want to publish a demo to view and use online. After try to publish an android emulator with unsuccessful results (very very slow even into top configuration machines in amazon), it would be a good try to install into a chrome OS. It is possible to deploy APKs in chrome os? Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It is possible to deploy APKs in chrome os? Are there alternatives?

No. V8 on Chrome OS & Dalvik on Android are 2 very different beasts. Perhaps you should try installing the apk on your system running [Android x86 project](http://www.android-x86.org/) & [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)

Comment: Android x86? This is a true surprise!!!! Thankns for your response and  your alternative :)

Comment: This solution is no longer relevant due to recent development: https://github.com/vladikoff/chromeos-apk